# Facebook - Unity3d desktop application

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, desktop-application

Currently ***unity facebook sdk*** is not supported in desktop version. How can I implement facebook login in unity desktop application?

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct, you cannot directly login to Facebook from a desktop app.

However, you can use `Application.OpenURL()` to fire up a browser window and grab the access token once the user logins to Facebook and gives your app the required privileges.

Here's a handy tutorial detailing all the steps:
http://www.ifc0nfig.com/accessing-facebook-unity-game-2/